# multiple programming try to access same text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I had created and text file using (AFL SCRIPTING LANGUAGE) this script will update (write) to a text file every 5 seconds. I will try to read file using vb.net, when I run the vb.net code form visual studio, everything works fine but (AFL script not able to update the text file), here is my vb.net code:

```
Dim FILE_NAME As New FileStream("C:\myreport\myfile.TXT", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)

REM Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\myreport\myfile.TXT"  

    REM Dim TextLine As String

    REM  If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        MYSTRING(I) = objReader.ReadLine()
        I = I + 1
    Loop

    REM End If
```

When I run the code above, ( AFL script not able to update the text file),

**Put simply:**

When I run the vb.net code (for accessing the text file),  AFL script not able to update.

1. I had share read/write the folder (where the text file exists), no effect, same problem I am facing.
2. Unchecked "Enable visual studio hosting process", still problem not solved.

Comment: You have some serious formatting issues with your post.  And lots of CAPS.  Please reformat.

Comment: Ouch, my ears... Why do you have to scream?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, the `FileSystemWatcher` class can help you with this problem.  You can read the file each time the file watcher says that the files has changed.  Here is the [reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read and write to a file from two processes at the same time. Well, technically you can, but it can lead to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) which is bad.

You need to implement some kind of shared locking mechanism around the file to prevent your two programs from fighting over it. Or, if you can guarantee that the consumer VB.NET program will have the file open for less than 5 seconds, you can go with [MrAxel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117997/681182) and simply have the VB.NET program read the file every time it is updated.